# How to replaceAll the numbers to Arabic or Persian

Tags: javascript, replaceall

I'm using const to define changes and took me so long. How can I use them and how can I brief the codes?:

```js
const [num0en, num1en, num2en, num3en, num4en, num5en, num6en, num7en, num8en, num9en, percEn] = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "%"]
const [num0fa, num1fa, num2fa, num3fa, num4fa, num5fa, num6fa, num7fa, num8fa, num9fa, PercFa] = ["۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹", "٪"]
const En0 = "0";
const Pe0 = "۰";
const En1 = '1';
const Pe1 = '۱';
const En2 = "2";
const Pe2 = "۲";
const En3 = "3";
const Pe3 = "۳";
const En4 = "4";
const Pe4 = "۴";
const En5 = "5";
const Pe5 = "۵";
const En6 = "6";
const Pe6 = "۶";
const En7 = "7";
const Pe7 = "۷";
const En8 = "8";
const Pe8 = "۸";
const En9 = "9";
const Pe9 = "۹";
const EnPercents = "%";
const PePercents = "٪";
const Rep0 = num0en.replaceAll(En0, Pe0);
const Rep1 = num1en.replaceAll(En1, Pe1);
const Rep2 = num2en.replaceAll(En2, Pe2);
const Rep3 = num3en.replaceAll(En3, Pe3);
const Rep4 = num4en.replaceAll(En4, Pe4);
const Rep5 = num5en.replaceAll(En5, Pe5);
const Rep6 = num6en.replaceAll(En6, Pe6);
const Rep7 = num7en.replaceAll(En7, Pe7);
const Rep8 = num8en.replaceAll(En8, Pe8);
const Rep9 = num9en.replaceAll(En9, Pe9);
const RepPer = percEn.replaceAll(EnPercents, PePercents);
const ReplaceAllNumbers = Rep0&&Rep1&&Rep2&&Rep3&&Rep4&&Rep5&&Rep6&&Rep7&&Rep8&&Rep9&&RepPer
    var post =  "0123456789";
// I need to use it in post below:
document.write(post);
```

and by the way, you would notice some mistakes. I beg you pardon beforehand..

Comment: What is `ReplacedAllNumbers` supposed to contain? And why aren't you using it? It's hard to tell what you are asking, all you're doing is printing a string (`post`) and ignoring all the code you wrote above.

Comment: Hi. thanks for the answer.
I'm trying to change for example every single 3 to ۳ wherever it is. In Person3 or 3241 or any other place. I'm trying to change them so the other parts of the post get no harm. And for egample if you use document.write(post), then you will get 3 as ۳ in it.

Comment: `document.write(Number(post).toLocaleString("fa-IR", {style: "decimal",useGrouping: false})`

Comment: when there's a word beside the numbers, it makes an error in Persian language! It writes: NoNumber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression, and use a function as the replacement so it can return the corresponding replacement. This correspondence can be in an object.

```
const enToPe = {
    [num0en]: num0fa,
    [num1en]: num1fa,
    ..
};

let result = post.replace(/./g, char => enToPe[char] || char);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var persianIran = "fa-IR"
var arabicEgypt = "ar-EG"

let num = 1234567890;

document.getElementById("num").innerText = num.toLocaleString(persianIran, {
  style: "decimal",
  useGrouping: false
});

document.getElementById("num1").innerText = num.toLocaleString(arabicEgypt, {
  style: "decimal",
  useGrouping: false
});

num = .42;
document.getElementById("pct").innerText = num.toLocaleString(persianIran, {
  style: "percent",
  useGrouping: true
});

document.getElementById("pct1").innerText = num.toLocaleString(arabicEgypt, {
  style: "percent",
  useGrouping: true
});

num = 1027;
document.getElementById("cur").innerText = num.toLocaleString(persianIran, {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "EUR"
});
document.getElementById("cur1").innerText = num.toLocaleString(arabicEgypt, {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "EUR"
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px
}

div>p:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Values</p>
  <p>1234567890 as Decimal</p>
  <p>.42 as Percent</p>
  <p>1027 as Currency</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Persian-Iran</p>
  <p id="num"></p>
  <p id="pct"></p>
  <p id="cur"></p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Arabic-Egypt</p>
  <p id="num1"></p>
  <p id="pct1"></p>
  <p id="cur1"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW: the html is for display only, look at the JS, That's where all the work is being done. As near as I can tell you did not need to do all those string replacements.